# How to append the value of Radiobutton to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

Am trying to append the value of `radiobutton` selected before printing the content in the entry field but am able to append the content in the `entry` widget to csv file. I would appreciate any help on how to go around achieve that.

```
from tkinter import *
import csv


with open ("profile.csv", "w") as db:
    writer = csv.writer(db)
    writer.writerow(["NAME ", "GENDER"]) # create with heading


def save_details():
    global e1               # global variable to receive the data from entry
    data = e1.get()
    #Sex = R1.get
    # Sex = R2.get()
    totalinput = [ data] # Sex here to append to the csv file
    with open("profile.csv", "a") as savedb:
        w = csv.writer(savedb)
        w.writerow(totalinput)


def validate():
    value = option.get()  # this for radiobutton

    now = new.get()  # this for an entry widget

    if value != "male" and value != "female":
        print("An option must be selected")
    else:
        print(now)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

new = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=new)

option = StringVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="MALE", value="male", var=option, 
command=save_details, indicatoron=0)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="FEMALE", value="female", var=option, 
command=save_details, indicatoron=0)
button = Button(root, text="OK", command=validate)


e1.pack()
R1.pack()
R2.pack()
button.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `option.get()` returns the selected value.

Comment: I clearly don't understand your question well enough without [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness bind  your `save_details()`  and `validate` function to the `OK` button.Then add you value to the `totalinput` list `totalinput = [ data, Sex]` to append both to the file.

```
from tkinter import *
import csv


with open ("profile.csv", "w") as db:
    writer = csv.writer(db)
    writer.writerow(["NAME ", "GENDER"]) # create with heading


def save_details():
    global e1               # global variable to receive the data from entry
    data = e1.get()
    Sex = option.get()   # this will get the value of radio selected and append it to the file
    totalinput = [ data, Sex] # Sex here to append to the csv file
    with open("profile.csv", "a") as savedb:
        w = csv.writer(savedb)
        w.writerow(totalinput)


def validate():
    value = option.get()  # this for radiobutton

    now = new.get()  # this for an entry widget

    if value != "male" and value != "female":
        print("An option must be selected")
    else:
        print(now)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

new = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=new)

option = StringVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="MALE", value="male", var=option, indicatoron=0)
R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="FEMALE", value="female", var=option, indicatoron=0)
button = Button(root, text="OK", command=lambda :[save_details(), validate()])


e1.pack()
R1.pack()
R2.pack()
button.pack(side="bottom")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: this how to get both entry content and radiobutton value to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
data = e1.get()
```

with:

```
data = option.get()
```

`Radiobutton`s share a variable that based on `Radiobutton`s' state that variable updates its value.

In your case `option`'s `value` is `"male"` if `R1` is selected and `"female"` if `R2` is selected, as in `option.get()` returns `"male"` or `"female"`.

Comment: As soon as i click on radiobutton it append the value to the file without clicking on the OK button

Comment: To my understanding i think he want both content in the entry and value for the radiobutton in a file